# ¿como traer el iduser de la base de datos y no el de la posición en la aparece en el jlist?

Tags: java, mysql

Se trata de capturar el iduser correcto en en un jList, 
tengo una validación para mostrar solo los registros activos entonces si tengo 15 usuarios y hay 2 inactivos  solamente me mostrara 13 y esto me esta causando problemas.

Lo de debe pasar es que cuando seleccione uno, se debe capturar en una variable todos los datos de usuario que están en la base de datos para usarlos en otras consultas.

Estaré muy agradecido, Llevo rato no he encontrado como hacerlo.

```
private void listaCampanaAValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                           

        int select = listaCampanaA.getSelectedIndex();
        DefaultListModel<String> modell = new DefaultListModel<>();
        if (select > 0) {
            try {
                Connection con = (Connection) Db.connect();
                Statement s;
                s = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE campana ='" + select + "'and estado = 1;");
                modell.addElement("TODOS");
                while (r.next()) {
                    modell.addElement(r.getString("nombreUsuario"));
                }
                listaUsuarioA.setModel(modell);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        } else {
            try {
                Connection con = (Connection) Db.connect();
                Statement s;
                s = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet a = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE estado = 1;");
                modell.addElement("TODOS");
                while (a.next()) {
                    modell.addElement(a.getString("nombreUsuario"));
                }
                listaUsuarioA.setModel(modell);
                listaUsuarioA.setSelectedIndex(0);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cuál es el error? Si lo depuras que te devuelve el objeto  ´ResultSet r´?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta en el JList el Index y separado por un delimitador Ejemplo

```
/*
    //...Coneccion base de datos
    //ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM campana ....");
    //...model listaCampanaA
     while (r.next()) {
            modell.addElement(r.getString("id")+":"+r.getString("nombreUsuario"));
     }
    //listaCampanaA.setModel(modell);
*/
private void listaCampanaAValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                           

        //int select = listaCampanaA.getSelectedIndex();
        String select = listaCampanaA.getSelectedValue().split(":")[0];

        DefaultListModel<String> modell = new DefaultListModel<>();
        if (listaCampanaA.getSelectedIndex()>0) {
            try {
                Connection con = (Connection) Db.connect();
                Statement s;
                s = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE idUser ='" + select + "' and estado = 1;"); //and campana = 
                modell.addElement("TODOS");
                while (r.next()) {
                    modell.addElement(r.getString("nombreUsuario"));
                }
                listaUsuarioA.setModel(modell);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        } else {
            try {
                Connection con = (Connection) Db.connect();
                Statement s;
                s = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet a = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE estado = 1;");
                modell.addElement("TODOS");
                while (a.next()) {
                    modell.addElement(a.getString("nombreUsuario"));
                }
                listaUsuarioA.setModel(modell);
                listaUsuarioA.setSelectedIndex(0);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```